# What is the opposite of acidic?

Tags: single-word-requests

Water with a low pH can be described as "acidic" water. How would you refer to water with a high pH?

I would guess it's "alkalitic" or "alkalinic," but I can't find any references to those words at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/).

Comment: What was wrong with *alkaline*?

Comment: I'd use "alkaline".  "Basic" might be technically correct  but is confusing.

Comment: @HotLicks 'Basic' is one of those words which translated to many other languages are less confusing. In English you're completely right.

Comment: "The alkalinity of the substance is very high."

Comment: Just say alkaline.  But what do you mean by "alkaline heavy water"?  "Heavy water" is D2O.  Water is H2O.  The D is deuterium, that is, heavy hydrogen, with one proton and one neutron in its nucleus.  (H has one proton in its nucleus.)   The pH of the water and the isotopic composition of the water are two entirely different things.  As for  alkalitic or alkalinic, no, simply no.

Comment: Is "basic" too basic for you?

Comment: Growing up as a Detroit Tigers fan, I always wondered why chemists were so obsessed with [Al Kaline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Kaline), or why they named batteries after him.

Comment: @stevesliva it just doesn't sound right, saying "this water is too alkaline"

Comment: @ab2 sorry that was just bad wording on my part. By "alkaline heavy" I meant water containing a lot of alkali as opposed to containing a lot of acid. (before the answers to this question I assumed alkaline was the opposite of acid, as opposed to alkali being the opposite of acid)

Comment: @DanielLawson -- No, no, no!!  Al Kaline is one of them ISIS dudes!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The commonly used antonym of acid is alkali, of acidic is alkaline. As you mention, acid/acidic refer to pH less than 7, alkali/alkaline to pH greater than 7, and neutral to pH equal to 7. In a long scientific career I have never met the term alkalitic and extremely rarely the term alkalinic.

Comment: So acid is to a alkali, as acidic is to alkaline? I guess I've just always wrongly assumed that the opposite of acid is alkaline. alkaline just sounds.. wrong though

Comment: I went with this as the answer due to the definitions by Oxford - *Alkaline* "Having the properties of an alkali, or containing alkali; having a pH greater than 7" - *Basic* "Having the properties of a base, or containing a base; having a pH above 7" - Alkaline seems to be more the opposite of acidic (if you think of acid being one side of neutral and alkali being the other)

Comment: @cantsay not all bases are alkalis, all alkalis are bases, all bases have pH above 7 in aqueous solutions. However, "acidic water" and "alkaline water" are set expressions used in a recent pseudoscience movement, so it would be the correct antonym in that context.

Comment: Bear in mind, though, that *acid* is commonly used as an adjective, both literally ('acid rain') and figuratively. The opposite then would be *alkaline* in the chemical sense (in the metaphorical sense, I would imagine *sweet*).

Answer (score 51):

"Basic" is the term for substances that are bases, opposite to substances that are "acidic", or acids.

Comment: That's true, I had forgotten that... But we did use alkalinic also.

Comment: @LamarLatrell "alkalinic" isn't a word. At least, it's not in any of the dictionaries I checked. It picks up some Google hits from people who use it to describe soils and foods, but it seems to be a mistaken attempt to turn "alkali" into an adjective. The accepted term is "alkaline".

Answer (score 16):

Strong bases can be described as `Caustic`. In Chemistry the word is reserved for those bases 'capable of burning, corroding, or destroying living tissue'. Although `Basic` and `Alkaline` are opposites of acidic as well, sometimes the stronger term is used for extra effect.

Here's [a Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caustic%2Calkalic%2Balkalinic%2Calkaline%2Balkali&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaustic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28alkalic%20%2B%20alkalinic%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28alkaline%20%2B%20alkali%29%3B%2Cc0) comparing the prevalence of caustic to alkaline, and two obscure terms from other answers: alkalic and alkalinic.

[image: Google ngram comparing caustic to alkanic+alkalinic]

Comment: Alkaline, not alkalic. "Alkalic" is a term in geology meaning a rock that's richer in sodium or potassium than normal.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Eh, I'm not sure how that snuck in there, I took over bad habits from the answers here.Updated the ngram to include the general term for alkaline.

Comment: That graph is probably at least somewhat skewed by alkaline *batteries*.

Comment: Strong acids can also be described as caustic, which means capable of corroding living tissue (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caustic).

Comment: @Marconius yeah.. somehow I have learnt that caustic only refers to bases, but it seems to be used more generally. Wikipedia: 'Sometimes the word 'caustic' is used as a synonym but 'caustic' generally refers only to strong bases, particularly alkalis, and not to acids, oxidizers, or other non-alkaline corrosives'

Comment: What I'm saying is that it would be wrong to use `caustic` referring to acids in the chemical sense, but since the word 'caustic' has been redefined (such that even *jokes* can be caustic) it can also be mis-used (in the chemical sense) for acids.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I heard "caustic" used to describe acids and bases growing up.  Not saying the usage is correct, but it does go back several decades.

Comment: @David 'Pretty sure' doesn't coincide with what is listed on Wikipedia:corrosive though...

Comment: @Spork It does match Merriam-Webster though. Anybody have the OED handy? :)

Comment: @David it can both be true.. formally incorrect usage, but correct under usage in an English novel, where jokes, relationships, and cats can all be Caustic - so why not acids.

Answer (score 9):

Alkaline or basic are the words to describe water with a high pH (That's how we've always described substances with a high pH in all my chemistry classes)

However, if you feel like you need an antonym with a closer equivalent to 'acidic' try [alkalic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alkalic?s=t)

Comment: Scroll to the British Dictionary definition

Comment: I suggest that you do not try alkalic, unless you clearly hear several of your profs or supervisors use that term.  Which I doubt you will.

Comment: I've never heard "alkalic" used in the context of chemistry, even in the UK.

Comment: I am sorry to say that in a long scientific career covering many aspects of chemistry, physics and other branches of science I have never encountered the word "alkalic".

Answer (score 3):

The word opposite of acidic would be basic.

A SOLUTION with low pH is considered acidic.
A solution with a high pH is considered basic.
Conversely, a solution with a low pOH is considered basic.
A solution with a high pOH is considered acidic.

Alkalinity is not the same property as basicity. Basicity describes the ratio of concentrations of H3O+ to OH- in a soution. Alkalinity describes a solution's ability to neutralize H+, regardless of pH/ pOH.

Comment: Supporting sources?

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of acidic is basic. Anything on the scale from 1-6 is acidic, and anything form 8-14 is basic